# Unity -> SceneManager.LoadScene(string) do not work in RELEASE

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have code:

```
[SerializeField]
Object[] _levels;

private void LoadLevel(int index)
{
    var level = _levels[index];
    SceneManager.LoadScene(level.name);
}
```

And this code works only from Unity Editor, but when I build it and run, an exception is thrown:

> (Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)
>
> Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
>   Thread -< id: 46c -< priority: 1 
>   All managers started up
>
> (Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 42)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   
>     at BeSlicer.Managering.MissionManager.LoadLevel (Int32 index) [0x00000] in filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at Messenger`1[System.Int32].Broadcast (System.String eventType, Int32 arg1, MessengerMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>   
>     at Messenger`1[System.Int32].Broadcast (System.String eventType, Int32 arg1) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at BeSlicer.GUI.UIController.OnContinueGame () [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>     at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown<:0 
>   
>   UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_LogException(Exception, Object)
>   
>   UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogException(Exception, Object)
>   
>   UnityEngine.Logger:LogException(Exception, Object)
>   
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
>   
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
>   
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMousePress(MouseButtonEventData)
>   
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent(Int32)
>   
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent()
>   
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
>   
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
>
> (Filename:  Line: -1)

I added all scenes to "Scenes in build" list, but it does not help.

I found that `SceneManager.LoadScene(int)` works good, the problem only with string version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object  at...

This is saying you are trying to access to an object that has not been initialized.

Check if the Object array `_levels` is not null when you enter `LoadLevel(int)` function. If it is null make sure to initialize that before doing `var level = _levels[index];`

Comment: I tried to assign scene asset to serialized field, but in release mode, reference to scene asset becomes NULL. So I change it to `string[]` and assign names explicitly and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
LoadLevel (Int32 index) [0x00000] in filename unknown<:0
```

LoadLevel method has two overloads,from the given error log i can see that unity is trying to load your level with an INT number not a String. probably your should cast it to string.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene((string)level.name);
```

or

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(level.name.toString());
```

Comment: Why didn't the language choose the correct override by default?  Casting is rarely the solution.

Comment: i don't know , maybe because of this : Object[] _levels; usually it should understand the correct overload , it's a programmer fault.

Comment: Indeed; and the question is poor as the `Level` class is not shown.  Why it wouldn't be `Level[] _levels;` is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that level.name is the correct scene name.

[Unity documentation:](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

"The given sceneName can either be the last part of the path, without .unity extension or the full path still without the .unity extension. The path has to be exactly as shown in the Build Settings Window. If only the scene name is given this will load the first scene in the list that matches. If you have multiple scenes with same name but different paths, you should use the full path."